# Get link collection from website through console

Tags: javascript, console

I'm trying to get collection of links from external website. Using this code:

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('_5syj');
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].attributes.href.nodeValue;
}
```

this returns only ONE link. Why is that ? What I should do to see all links in log ?

Comment: Are you scraping them in console or in an iframe?

Comment: First check the length of captured links with : document.getElementsByClassName('_5syj').length

Comment: It's 18, so should work fine I guess

Comment: Also, I tried custom integer, the result is the same.

Comment: And If I use alert inside FOR loop, it alerts all values.

Comment: Have you considered using [*document.links*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#dom-document-links)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use console.log method

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('_5syj'); 
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) { 
    console.log(links[i].attributes.href.nodeValue); 
}
```

Comment: That's weird, at first it didn't worked, but now it works.. Thanks!